# convert an array to json in laravel controller

Tags: php, json, laravel

Hy Guys, I have a problem again. and this time with my laravel project.

I have a controller function like this:

```
public function postDetail(Request $request)
{
  $product_requests = $request->sku;
  $arr = [];
}
```

And my `$request->sku` looked like this:

```
[612552892 => ['quantity' => '1'], 625512336 => ['quantity' => '10']]
```

but i need the json file like this:

```
[{"sku_id": 612552892, "quantity": "1"}, {"sku_id": 625512336, "quantity": "10"}]
```

so, should i make the key too? but.. How ?

and I think I have to make it in foreach loop right? anyone can help me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to convert array into proper form after that apply `json_encode()`like below:

```
$arrSku = array('612552892' => array('quantity' => 1), '625512336' => array('quantity' => 10) );

$arrNewSku = array();
$incI = 0;
foreach($arrSku AS $arrKey => $arrData){
    $arrNewSku[$incI]['sku_id'] = $arrKey;
    $arrNewSku[$incI]['quantity'] = $arrData['quantity'];
    $incI++;
}

//Convert array to json form...
$encodedSku = json_encode($arrNewSku);

print('<pre>');
print_r($encodedSku);
print('</pre>');

//Output:
[{"sku_id":612552892,"quantity":1},{"sku_id":625512336,"quantity":10}]
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: You should initiate the associative array (sku, quantity) when creating the index `$incI` otherwise you'll get tons of warnings

Comment: @JulienLachal I tested my code at [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) before I place it here and working fine without any single error. Hope you understand.

Comment: @ajussi: Happy to help you!

Answer (score 10):

Use `$encodedSku = json_encode($request->sku);` and you'll have a proper JSON instead of an Array.

Comment: aaah! it change, you are right.. but it does not have the `sku_id` key

Comment: then you'll have to change the keys in the array, or create a new array from your first one. `json_encode` cannot guess the keys you need ;)